# Need help to remove protective cover from light bulb

Tags: lighting

I need to remove this protective cover from my light fixture. I've tried to turn the protective cover, ive pulled on it, and I've tried to remove this specific light from the fixture.

I've tried the same on the other 2 working lights with no success as well, so I'm at a loss. I haven't had the bulb burn out since I bought the house 5 years ago and have no instruction manuals or know the name of the fixture to be able to look up online how to take it off.

Would really appreciate any guidance that anyone has on how to remove it.

[image]

[image]!

Comment: Hi Ashley, welcome to our DIY site. Would you be able to post another picture looking at the light from the side? It is a little difficult seeing what you have there from just the view looking up into it.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a set screw on the metal base, perpendicular to the direction that you insert the bulb (or parallel to the plane of the ceiling). There might even be 2 or 3 screws. You need to loosen (but not remove) them, they hook under a lip of the glass enclosure to hold it in place. Be careful to not drop it.

I circled the screws in this photo:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Z4-tier! Unfortunately there is nothing on the side of the light. As per Michaels recommendation I've added in a picture of the side of the light

Answer (score 2):

I have similar fittings, and they have a threaded collar inside the fitting, at the base of the Edison-screw connector:

[image: Inside view of light]

They came with a little tool for removing them.

[image: Removal tool]

You could probably fashion a tool from some thin sheet material, or maybe a (very) large pair of bent tweezers?

Comment: Correct, Sometimes the cover is big enough to allow you to get your hand inside  ( with the lightbulb removed ) and get your fingers on the ring. If it wasn’t tightened down too much you can get it to turn with your fingertips. But you need to be careful not to put your finger inside the socket, make sure the power is off.

Comment: After removing the light bulb, you may be able to simply unscrew the glass shade.